# Json array to display in view of angular

Tags: json, angular, laravel

I pulled the data from laravel api like this

```js
this.dataService.geData().subscribe(res=>{
      this.contacts=res
    });
```

I got json array return from Laravel like below and i want to loop this to display in view of angular 14.

```
    {
    "status":true,
    "contacts":
    [
        {"id":1,"name":"Christopher","email":"christopher@gmail.com"},
        {"id":2,"name":"Anthony","email":"anthony@gmail.com"},
        {"id":3,"name":"John Lenon","email":"john@hotmail.com"}
    ]   
}
```

I tried this but it is not displaying anything

```html
<tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let contact of contacts">
            <td>{{contact.id}}</td>
            <td>{{contact.name}}</td>
            <td>{{contact.email}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: this.contacts=res should be this.contacts=res.contacts

Comment: I tried that but got error : Property 'contacts' does not exist on type 'Object'.

Answer (score 1):

Your code

```
this.dataService.geData().subscribe(res=>{
  this.contacts=res
});
```

store the result (res variable) of the call to the Laravel backend in the contacts variable.

If the answer from laravel is

```
{
    "status":true,
    "contacts":
    [
        {"id":1,"name":"Christopher","email":"christopher@gmail.com"},
        {"id":2,"name":"Anthony","email":"anthony@gmail.com"},
        {"id":3,"name":"John Lenon","email":"john@hotmail.com"}
    ]   
}
```

you are storing the whole answer in the variable contacts (not only the contacts property). So you have two ways to solve this problem.
The first solution is storing in the contacts variable the value of the contacts property of the answer as follow:

```
this.dataService.geData().subscribe(res=>{
   // Change res to res.contacts
   this.contacts = res.contacts;
});
```

The second way is to save the whole answer in a new variable

```
this.dataService.geData().subscribe(res=>{
   this.wholeAnswer = res;
});
```

and change the front end to loop through the contacts inside that variable:

```
<tbody>
    <!-- looping through wholeAnswer.contacts, not just wholeAnswer -->
    <tr *ngFor="let contact of wholeAnswer.contacts">
        <td>{{contact.id}}</td>
        <td>{{contact.name}}</td>
        <td>{{contact.email}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Tried this "this.contacts = res.contacts;" but getting error Property 'contacts' does not exist on type 'Object'.

Comment: try to use any type and eventually create the right type if it works

Answer (score 0):

As explained in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72872088/json-array-to-display-in-view-of-angular#comment128711360_72872088) you're not accessing the good variable.

That said I'd recommend a more reactive approach:

```
public contacts$ = this.dataService.geData().pipe(
  map(res=> res.contacts)
);
```

and the view:

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let contact of contacts$ | async">
    <td>{{contact.id}}</td>
    <td>{{contact.name}}</td>
    <td>{{contact.email}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```